# c++: run-time conflict of same functions defined in different linked libraries

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, g++, gsoap

I have the following problem:
To my Qt application I link several shared (.so) libraries and some of them include soapC.cpp files which are automatically generated gSoap source files. The soapC.cpp files are not exactly the same in the different .so libraries but they contain many identical functions, lets call them foo().

When I build my application I link all these libraries in a specific order, let's say lib1.so, lib2.so, lib3.so,... etc. and the compilation runs smoothly (I'm using g++ compiler v. 4.6).

When I run my application however I noticed that when a piece of code, say in lib3.so, tries to call foo() which is also defined in lib3.so, for some reasons foo() from lib1.so is called instead. This causes troubles and my application segfaults.

My question is, is there any c++/linker option that I could pass to the compiler which would cause that during the run-time of my application really foo() from lib3.so, from where is it called, would be executed and not foo() from lib1.so? I was trying -Bsymbolic and -Bsymbolic-functions without luck.

A possible solution to this is using namespaces, but due to a big complexity of the code this is rather a last possible solution. 
If there would be a quick and easy solution to this it would be great. Btw. I'm doing this under Ubuntu, under Windows the same code works perfectly and does what it should...

Comment: I think the robust fix would be to add namespace support to gsoap's code generator, or use it should it be already there. Note that https://github.com/KDAB/KDSoap supports namespaces :) (Disclaimer: I work for KDAB)

Comment: Thanks, I know but as I said, namespaces are rather last option simply because the code refactoring in all of the project would be simply too large... I'm more looking for a shortcut...

Answer (score 1):

I assume the conflicting functions are in generated code?

Namespaces are the easiest fix, you do not have to namespace every header and cpp file, just wrap them! Create a single header and cpp file for each library, and #include all of the generated headers and source files in each, and only compile the wrapper cpp into the library. Also will limit breakage should files be regenerated (at worst, have to add header or cpp to your wrapper).

lib1.h

```
namespace lib1 {
#include "generated header 1.h"
#include "generated header 2.h"
#include "generated header 3.h"
}
```

lib1.cpp

```
namespace lib1 {
#include "generated source file 1.cpp"
#include "generated source file 2.cpp"
#include "generated source file 3.cpp"
}
```